# iOS - Second View is not displaying over tab view

Tags: ios, view, tabbar

I have a tabBarView and a GWDNativeViewController. GWDNativeViewController is a main menu. I am trying to get that view to display first and overtop the tabBarView. I have this same code set within an IBAction and it works. When I put it into the Loaddidfinishwithoptions it doesn't work.

```
@implementation GWDNativeAppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize tabBarController = _tabBarController;
@synthesize secondView = _secondView;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[GWDNativeFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GWDNativeFirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[GWDNativeSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GWDNativeSecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[GWDNativeThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GWDNativeThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController4 = [[GWDNativeFourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GWDNativeFourthViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController5 = [[GWDNativeFifthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GWDNativeFifthViewController" bundle:nil];

    //tabBarController Stuff
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, viewController3, viewController4, viewController5, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

    //Specify W`enter code here`hich tab to display (Number need to be set based on button selected)
    //self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;       

    GWDNativeViewController *secondView = [[GWDNativeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [secondView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:secondView animated:YES];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Here is the the code in the GWDNativeFirstViewController.m
The code in the IBAction works.. Code in the viewDidLoad doesn't.?

```
-(IBAction)pressedButton {

    GWDNativeViewController *secondView = [[GWDNativeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [secondView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [self presentModalViewController:secondView animated:YES];
    //[secondView release];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"First", @"First");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first"];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [contentWebView1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://m.web.org/?iapp=1#tab1"]]];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

     GWDNativeViewController *secondView = [[GWDNativeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
     [secondView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
     [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:secondView animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Does secondView have a view? You say it doesn't work -- what do you see?

Comment: I just edited the post to include the working code. It doesn't do anything in addition to displaying the tabBarController when simply placed in the in viewDidLoad. However the same code works when used as an IBAction..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it doesn't work in viewDidLoad, but it can work in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: if you put your [self.window makeKeyAndVisible] line before you define secondView.

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
 GWDNativeViewController *secondView = [[GWDNativeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
 [secondView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
 [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:secondView animated:YES];
```

If you want it to appear immediately, change the animated option to NO, and delete the line defining the modalTransitionStyle.

Comment: This was the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The tabBarController's view hasn't loaded here yet. You could put that code into the viewDidLoad in one of your 5 view controllers.

Comment: Thank you for the response. That is a good thought. I tried putting it there just now (cleaned and rebuild) but it did not make it appear.

Comment: are you still trying to present it from your tab bar? You should present it from the view controller whose viewDidLoad it's in. That should work.